# Word wrap different firefox, IE, chrome, mobile browsers

Tags: css

I have text with a background image of a fixed width and height. I want the text to be a fixed number of lines (3). The text wraps differently in different browsers, sometimes inserting an extra line which makes the text go over the boundary of the background image. This means I have to add/remove words from my text and continually check the rendering in each browser to see that it is the same number of lines.

I am guessing that either the browsers are rounding the width/margin/padding so that the width of the container is different, or that the text is rendered slightly differently in each browser (with more or less width).

What would be the recommended practice for this? I want the text in the container to be no more than 3 lines long, so I am just as well to fix the height of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *recommended* practice is not do something like this. Try to redesign so that the background image isn't/doesn't need to be of fixed height and the text doesn't need to be limited to exactly three lines. If this is some kind of requirement imposed on you by your boss/customer, you'll need to talk with them and explain, that this isn't something one can or should do in HTML/CSS.

Keep in mind, that not only the width of the characters will be different in each browser resulting in different wrapping, but browsers will display the text **lines** in different heights, too, so it can be that your element can't contain three lines.

If you have no other choice, consider using `overflow: hidden` on the fixed-size element, however this will most likely lead to cut off letters and/or words.

---

**EDIT re comment:**

I don't think the available space would variate between browsers. If you were using relative units (`em`, `%`), then maybe there would be rounding differences of one pixel max. However you are using pixels, which should be identical in all current browsers (in Standards Mode).

Anyway I'm not saying you should restrict the amount of text you want to display, just give the text some space to "breath" and don't give the element a fixed height in pixels. Instead:

- Set a `line-height` (for example `1.25`) and a `min-height` three times the amount (here `3.75em`).
- Use your best estimate to limit the text you want to put in there to three lines.
- Add some JavaScript that shortens the text, in case it does happen to go over three lines.
- Adjust your layout (including a flexible background for that element), so it can survive both a few pixels difference due to different browser's (and more importantly the user's preferred) font size **and** can survive an additional line of text just in the seldom case that you mis-estimated the text length and JavaScript isn't available.

Comment: I have seen the width of characters being different in different browsers. Also, I think even with the same padding, margin and width, the available space within a div differs accross browsers. Anyhow, I need to make the background a fixed height so that it does not take up too much space above the fold. Text is overlaid on the background to give small twitter like updates. So, there is a reason for restricting to 3 lines and a certain height.

Comment: @EDIT, seems like good pragmatic advice. Checking how each browser renders the text is the first option. Then back this up with Javascript and flexible background element. I just wanted to see if I was missing something that would solve this easily. It seems like it would be a common requirement to have a fixed number of lines of text and a fixed height background image.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a good CSS reset as most browsers have different defaults for various tags. Assuming your reset is good, you can use browser specific CSS to account for differences in rendering.

Comment: Even the best reset style sheet can't account for different fonts or user preferences overriding font sizes. A good design, however can and should account for these.

Comment: Clients/bosses often don't care about good design so we make do within the parameters given whether it's the right way to do it or not.

Comment: When the text goes onto 4 lines, wouldn't you have to use javascript to shorten the text?